# Undefined Index: 0

Tags: php

Getting this error in my log, here is the line it's referring to:

```
<div class="<?php echo $divclass; ?>" id="product-item-<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
    <?php echo $products_name[$product_id]; ?>
    <img src="view/image/delete.png" />
    <input name="bossmegamenu[product_ids][]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
</div>
```

This is a opencart module.

Any ideas how to track this down?

Comment: $products_name[$product_id]; this is probably empty, try var_dump($products_name) to see what you have inside

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply; I tried the var_dump but no results. It's throwing different number in there, sometimes none:
Undefined index:
Undefined index:  4Undefined index:  6Undefined index:

Comment: is your array empty ?

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, the 'type' is innoDB with -9 rows. All the other types are MYISAM..could the problem be on database end?

Comment: try to see where you are making your array, it must be a problem there

Comment: for simple select, innodb or myisam don't change anything

Comment: Okay so this is what I was able to come up with:
The unidentified index is referring to the "item" column.
    ss here (http://i60.tinypic.com/27yqwsn.jpg)
Depending on the selection options, a series of numbers is created like: 4, 6, (sometimes it remains blank)

but as soon as I hit save, I get the following errors:
Undefined index:  4
Undefined index:  6
Undefined index:  (blank)

This appears to be the file controlling the array and parameter info (http://ge.tt/5mnFdYo1/v/0?c)

Thanks Thomas for the help thus far, I just can't seem to figure this out 4 hours later

Comment: This is the file that post the information to the database (http://ge.tt/9qGVhYo1/v/0?c)

Comment: Questions regarding specific code related to OpenCart should be posted on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart